# How to load a patched library

Tags: load-path, load, libraries

I've applied a [patch](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2021-12/msg01040.html) to `/usr/share/emacs/27.2/lisp/isearch.el.gz` to fix a [bug](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2021-12/msg00665.html), recompiled it, but I can't get Emacs to load the fixed version. The patch works because I can take the two function definitions it changes, evaluate them, and the bug goes away.

One thing that I don't understand is that I tried renaming both the compressed source code (`isearch.el.gz`) and the byte-compiled binary (`isearch.elc`) in `/usr/share/emacs/27.2/lisp/`, I launched Emacs and it still had functioning Isearch, only the documentation didn't display the link to the library.

There's two things that may be worth to point out:

- I have the full Emacs source tree in `~/.rpmbuild/BUILD/emacs-27.2/` (I've renamed the library even there, still didn't make a difference);
- I set `load-prefer-newer` to `t` in my init file, but I've also tried without that setting and it still didn't work.

Comment: If you do `M-x locate-library RET isearch RET` (or whatever name you changed it to), Emacs should tell you which library it has loaded (or will load) exactly. Make sure that that matches your expectations.

Comment: See `loadup.el` ...  Certain libraries are baked into the executable when going through the `make` process. If `isearch.el` is one of them, then you'll need to evaluate your patched version after Emacs starts up.  In addition, certain variables (such as those assigned with `defvar`) will need special treatment if you change the value of the `defvar` without using something like `setq` ...  I haven't studied the preload libraries of 27.2, but you might want to check that out.  I have certain libraries that are custom which I patch before building Emacs, such as my own `startup.el` ...

Comment: @NickD `M-x locate-library RET isearch RET` says `No library isearch in search path`. If I do `M-x locate-library RET isearch_ORIG RET` it says `Library is file /usr/share/emacs/27.2/lisp/isearch_ORIG.elc` but I guess Emacs doesn't know it should look for isearch there, right?

Comment: @lawlist Interesting. There's `(load "isearch")` in my `loadup.el` so that may be the cause of the issue.

Comment: @lawlist I've added `(unload-feature 'isearch)` `(load-file "~/.emacs.d/local/patched-libraries/isearch/isearch.elc")` to my init file and it works but I'm not sure it's the best way to go. Do you have any advice against doing that? Interestingly, `locate-library` still returns `Library is file /usr/share/emacs/27.2/lisp/isearch.elc` even though it can't be because loading that file would display the bug.

Comment: One idea would be to add *only* the two (2) revised/patched functions (in their entirety) to your `.emacs` file and they will take the place of the stock versions once your `.emacs` file is evaluated on Emacs launch: `isearch-message-prefix` and `isearch-search-fun-default`.   To verify they have superseded the stock versions after launching Emacs with the `.emacs` file containing the revised functions, you can type:  `M-x find-function RET isearch-message-prefix` and also `isearch-search-fun-default`.  In both test cases, Emacs should jump to those revised functions within your `.emacs` file.

Comment: Another idea, if you enjoy building your own Emacs, would be to patch the original source file (isearch.el) prior to running the `make` command.  And yet another idea, if the Emacs team already patched the repository, you can just build a version from that point in time (commit) forward ... but, it would be necessary to find out what branch or the master if applicable.

Comment: You don't say *how* you are telling Emacs to load the library. Something like `require` won't load it, if some version of it has already been loaded. `load-library` should work, provided it's in your `load-path` (which is consulted before other locations).

Comment: @lawlist > _One idea would be to add only the two (2) revised/patched functions (in their entirety) to your `.emacs`._ Yes that's simpler, in the end I kept only those two functions in my patched file and added just `(load-file "~/.emacs.d/local/patches/isearch/isearch-patched-functions.el")` to my init. > _if you enjoy building your own Emacs…_ No, I'm (still) missing out here :-) Anyway, if you turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it.